# if statement not being respected in PHP

Tags: php

```
if ($fromcat == "true" || $fromcat == 1){

    error_log("binding to CAT " . $cat . " because pfc was " . $fromcat);   

} else {

    error_log("binding to ROOM " . $room . " because pfc was " . $fromcat); 

}
```

please have a look at the code above.

I think everybody agree that if `$fromcat` is 0 there's no way I could get a "binding to CAT (...)" message in my console.

And yet, here it is:

```
[01-Apr-2013 22:34:50] binding to CAT single because pfc was 0
```

How is that even possible? You can't display the word CAT and the number 0 at the same time! Is PHP drunk?

Comment: What happens if you use the `===` operator instead of `==`?

Comment: Unfortunately, `0 == "true"` is true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the identical (`===`) comparison operator.

```
if ($fromcat === "true" || $fromcat === 1) {

    error_log("binding to CAT " . $cat . " because pfc was " . $fromcat);   

} else {

    error_log("binding to ROOM " . $room . " because pfc was " . $fromcat); 

}
```

You are attempting to compare `$fromcat` to the string `"true"`. If you wanted to compare it to the boolean true, you would use `$fromcat == true`. Otherwise:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: I didn't know that! Just wasted an entire day of work just to track down this bug and fix it... Thanks a lot! Will mark as correct as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It's also a good idea to reverse the order of your condition.

So

```
if ($fromcat === "true" || $fromcat === 1)
```

becomes

```
if ('true' === $fromcat || 1 === $fromcat)
```

Reason: [PHP - reversed order in if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849667/php-reversed-order-in-if-statement)