# Wordpress cookie is only available from one page even though it is set for entire domain

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I have set a cookie in my functions.php as follows:

```
add_action('send_headers', 'sfdc_cookie');
function sfdc_cookie() {
    if( isset($_GET['sfdc']) && '' != $_GET['sfdc'] ) {
        if( empty($_COOKIE['sfdc']) ){
            if ($_GET['sfdc'] == 'mim'):
            setcookie('sfdc', 'cookievalue', time()+3156000, '/', 'www.mydomain.com' );
            //$_COOKIE['sfdc'] = 'cookie';
            endif;
        }                          
    }
    echo $_COOKIE['sfdc'];
}
```

if I access any page on the site with ?sfdc=mim, the value is shown.  I assumed the cookie is set at that point, and when I check the stored cookies from the Chrome browser, it appears to be set.  However, if the querystring is absent, it is as if the cookie does not exist.  I cannot even echo the cookie onto the page..  Why can't I echo the value when the querystring is not present in the URL?

I have changed my add_action from send_headers to init with the same result.

Comment: maybe you want to use `$_SESSION` variable? it works for me rly good. You can also check if `session` is already started and if not, you can start it and then you check for session variables. is this helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You should fire up this function like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'sfdc_cookie' ); // <-- this starts the function with the same name in the location named 'wp_enqueue_scripts' 
function sfdc_cookie() {
if( isset($_GET['sfdc']) && '' != $_GET['sfdc'] ) {
    if( empty($_COOKIE['sfdc']) ){
        if ($_GET['sfdc'] == 'mim')
        {
        setcookie('sfdc', 'cookievalue', time()+3156000, '/', 'www.mydomain.com' );
        //$_COOKIE['sfdc'] = 'cookie';
        }
    }                          
}
```

if you want start cookie on page and make it available in others, you should do it like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'sfdc_cookie' );
function sfdc_cookie() {
   if( !isset($_COOKIE['sfdc']) ) {
      setcookie('sfdc', 'cookievalue', time()+3156000, '/', 'www.mydomain.com' );
   }
}
```

Comment: never seen `endif` in php. Is it some `wordpress` specific thing or what?

Comment: @JonNezbit yes, you can use it in WP or in Laravel but not this way.

Comment: endif is used in PHP all the time. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php

Comment: @Kafus your solution did not work.  It does not appear to set the cookie at all when I use wp_enqueue_scripts as opposed to send_headers.  I cleared the cookie before testing and it would not set or echo.

Comment: @osakagreg try to use it in `init` not in `wp_enqueue_scripts` - location `init` is on every wordpress page, so it will be:    add_action( 'init', 'sfdc_cookie' ).

Comment: @Kafus I'm having the same issue using init.  It is available only on the page from which it is set.    I see the cookie in my Chrome settings, but it is not be read on other pages.

Comment: @osakagreg so you want this cookie in all pages? If so, you have bad `if`s. I'll change it for you

Comment: @osakagreg I eddited my Asnwer. You can add `if( isset($_GET['sfdc'])` if you want.  But code `'' != $_GET['sfdc']` is quite strange. it means: if `nothing` is not equal `$_GET['sfdc']

Comment: @Kafus that's just making sure it's set and has a value.  Anyhow, I tried and it still does not work beyond one page.  You left a closing parenthesis in your code: if( !isset($_COOKIE['sfdc'] ) {

Comment: @osakagreg "that's just making sure it's set and has a value" - if you wanna do this it should be: `isset($_GET['sfdc']) && $_GET['sfdc'] != '' `. About question: if you set `domain`- try to remove `www` or even try to remove last two parameters: `path` and `domain`

Comment: @Kafus I think it's standard. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10849667/php-reversed-order-in-if-statement.  Anyhow, I have tried changing the domain values.  Nothing works.  Maybe there is a plugin conflict or something else weird going on.  I'm bending over backwards just to get a cookie value.  I'll try this on a different installation of WP that has no plugins and see what happens.